# Get debug log output of Gradle build in Gitlab CI / CD

Tags: debugging, gradle, gitlab-ci

how i can make Gitlab CI / CD runner to show the full output of `gradle --debug` like i get on my local machine:

`local-machine` :

```
15:29:31.077 [INFO] [org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.services.NativeServices] Initialized native services in: /home/lukjaw/.gradle/native
15:29:32.022 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Executing build b9005788-6c5e-457d-b76d-7ff09d72a3c5.1 in daemon client {pid=10139}
15:29:32.048 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface docker0
15:29:32.050 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
15:29:32.061 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
15:29:32.068 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote address /172.17.0.1
15:29:32.068 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote multicast interface docker0
15:29:32.069 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface enp0s3
15:29:32.069 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? false
15:29:32.069 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? true
15:29:32.071 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote address /fe80:0:0:0:a00:27ff:fee5:7859%enp0s3
15:29:32.071 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote address /10.0.2.15
15:29:32.073 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding remote multicast interface enp0s3
15:29:32.074 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding IP addresses for network interface lo
15:29:32.076 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a loopback interface? true
15:29:32.076 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Is this a multicast interface? false
15:29:32.076 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback address /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo
15:29:32.076 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.InetAddresses] Adding loopback address /127.0.0.1
15:29:32.099 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:29:32.104 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
15:29:32.119 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:29:32.132 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector] Attempting to connect to [9a2e5900-8640-4df4-9eb2-bae4c1268af0 port:42663, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]].
15:29:32.133 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector] Trying to connect to address /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1.
15:29:32.203 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.TcpOutgoingConnector] Connected to address /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:42663.
15:29:32.367 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Connected to daemon DaemonInfo{pid=1423, address=[9a2e5900-8640-4df4-9eb2-bae4c1268af0 port:42663, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1586178094502, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=c21b8cfc-c332-478f-935f-42452ca928fd,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64,daemonRegistryDir=/home/lukjaw/.gradle/daemon,pid=1423,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]}. Dispatching request Build{id=b9005788-6c5e-457d-b76d-7ff09d72a3c5.1, currentDir=/home/lukjaw/repos/int-k0026-jde-siteinfomanager}.
15:29:32.379 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClientConnection] thread 1: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.Build
15:29:32.829 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient] Received result org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildStarted@389b0789 from daemon DaemonInfo{pid=1423, address=[9a2e5900-8640-4df4-9eb2-bae4c1268af0 port:42663, addresses:[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, /127.0.0.1]], state=Idle, lastBusy=1586178094502, context=DefaultDaemonContext[uid=c21b8cfc-c332-478f-935f-42452ca928fd,javaHome=/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64,daemonRegistryDir=/home/lukjaw/.gradle/daemon,pid=1423,idleTimeout=10800000,daemonOpts=-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError,-Xmx1024m,-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8,-Duser.country=US,-Duser.language=en,-Duser.variant]} (build should be starting).
15:29:32.763 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient] The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 1423). The daemon log file: /home/lukjaw/.gradle/daemon/4.4.1/daemon-1423.out.log
15:29:32.801 [INFO] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth] Starting 3rd build in daemon [uptime: 29 mins 3.75 secs, performance: 98%]
15:29:32.813 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild] The daemon has started executing the build.
```

Gitlab runner output:

```
Starting Build

> Loading > settings > Compiling script into cacheCompiling settings file '/workspace/settings.gradle' using SubsetScriptTransformer.
> Loading > settings > Compiling script into cache
> Loading > settings > Compiling script into cache > Compiling script into cacheCompiling settings file '/workspace/settings.gradle' using BuildScriptTransformer.
> Loading > settings > Compiling script into cache
> Loading > settings > Compiling script into cacheSettings evaluated using settings file '/workspace/settings.gradle'.
> Loading
> LoadingConfiguringProjects loaded. Root project using build file '/workspace/build.gradle'.
> Configuring
> ConfiguringIncluded projects: [root project 'int-k0026-jde-siteinfomanager']
> Configuring
> Configuring > 0/1 projects > root projectEvaluating root project 'int-k0026-jde-siteinfomanager' using build file '/workspace/build.gradle'.
> Configuring > 0/1 projects > root project
> Configuring > 0/1 projects > root project > Compiling script into cacheCompiling build file '/workspace/build.gradle' using SubsetScriptTransformer.
> Configuring > 0/1 projects > root project > Compiling script into cache
```

How i can get the exact same `gradle --debug` output as i get on local machine ?

The problem that i want to debug is to check why the build on gitrunner (only for this particular project) is taking very long time, even to download the dependencies.

I am using : (i know its outdated but this is what i have now)

```
GitLab11.1.2 (35936b0)
GitLab Shell7.1.4
GitLab Workhorsev5.0.0
GitLab APIv4
GitLab runner using Shell executor
```